# Arithmetic in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}$

Tags: finite-fields

In this document: *"The Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)" - Don Johnson, Alfred Menezes, Scott Vanstone*; in section 4.2 example 7 there is some finite field arithmetic:

Given $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{2^4}$ the following is claimed:
$$
\begin{align*}
& \quad \left( \frac{\alpha^8 + \alpha^{13}}{\alpha^6+\alpha^3} \right)^2 + \frac{\alpha^8 + 
\alpha^{13}}{\alpha^6+\alpha^3} + \alpha^6 + \alpha^3 + \alpha^4 \\
&=\left( \frac{\alpha^3}{\alpha^2} \right)^2 + \frac{\alpha^3}{\alpha^2} + \alpha^6 + \alpha^3 + \alpha^4 \\
&= 1
\end{align*}
$$

I don't understand the simplification that is happening line-by-line. I tried using some concrete examples, like $\alpha=x$ or $\alpha=x+1$ and then sure enough the simplification works out (I used https://wims.math.cnrs.fr/wims/wims.cgi to double check my working).

The irreducible poly chosen in the text is $f(x) = x^4 + x + 1$ (not sure if it's relevant in the general case for $\alpha$).

Comment: Please provide a link to the paper

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20170921160141/http://cs.ucsb.edu/~koc/ccs130h/notes/ecdsa-cert.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit earlier, in section 3.2.1, example 2, they explicitly say $\alpha=x$.

Comment: Thanks! It seems though that $\alpha$ is used as a generic element of the field, which is stated at the top of section 3.2. Also, the equation is satisfied for $\alpha=x+1$, not just $\alpha=x$

Comment: Nvm, seems you are correct ser!

Answer (score 1):

It is very relevant which polynomial we choose to extend $\Bbb F_2$ to $\Bbb F_{2^4}$. It tells us that $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial, and therefore that $\alpha^4+\alpha+1=0$, alternately that $\alpha^4+\alpha=1$ or $\alpha^4=\alpha+1$ (remember we are in characteristic $2$). Using this we get
$$
\alpha^{13}=\alpha\cdot(\alpha^4)^3=\alpha\cdot(\alpha+1)^3=\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha\\
=(\alpha+1)+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha=\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1
$$
Similarly we get
$$
\alpha^8=(\alpha^4)^2=(\alpha+1)^2=\alpha^2+1
$$
Adding these two together yields $\alpha^8+\alpha^{13}=\alpha^3$. A very similar but simpler calculation yields $\alpha^6+\alpha^3=\alpha^2$.

Obviously we have $\frac{\alpha^3}{\alpha^2}=\alpha$, and the rest is simply collecting like terms and cancelling using $2=0$.

Comment: Thank you! This is super insightful. I didn't know that $f(\alpha)=0 \space \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ if $f$ is the extension poly.

Comment: @Stent Wait, $\alpha$ is supposed to be _any_ element of $\Bbb F_{2^4}$? I missed that. I thought you just had $\Bbb F_{2^4}=\Bbb F_2(\alpha)$ for a particular $\alpha$ that is chosen to be the root of $f$. It is certainly _not_ true for any $\alpha\in\Bbb F_{2^4}$. In particular $0$ and $1$ makes the fractions undefined, as would any element of $\Bbb F_{2^2}$, and I'm sure there are other issues with other elements.

Comment: Ah it must be that I got lucky with my test values! Seems @MigMit's answer is right then.

Answer (score 0):

By assumption we have $2=0$ and $\alpha^4=\alpha+1$, so that $\alpha^6=\alpha^3+\alpha^2$. Now the computation is just
$$
\left( \frac{\alpha^3}{\alpha^2} \right)^2 + \frac{\alpha^3}{\alpha^2} + \alpha^6 + \alpha^3 + \alpha^4 =2(\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^3)+1=1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I prepared [this Q&A pair](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619) with exactly referrals like this in mind. The discrete logarithm table in that answer applies here, because I also used $f(x)=x^4+x+1$ as the primitive polynomial. The only difference is that I denoted by $\gamma$ what your source calls $\alpha$ (mostly because $\alpha$ had a different meaning in my post, normally I would also denote it $\alpha$ :-).

I will show how to use that table.

- We have $\alpha^8=\alpha^2+1$ and $\alpha^{13}=\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1$, so $\alpha^8+\alpha^{13}=\alpha^3$.
- We have $\alpha^6=\alpha^3+\alpha^2$, so $\alpha^6+\alpha^3=\alpha^2$.
- Therefore $(\alpha^8+\alpha^{13})/(\alpha^3+\alpha^6)=\alpha^3/\alpha^2=\alpha$.
- $\alpha^4=\alpha+1$, so that formula evaluates to
  $$\alpha^2+\alpha+(\alpha^3+\alpha^2)+\alpha^3+(\alpha+1)=1.$$